# Add tabBarItem From Non TabBarViewController Or ContainerViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have a **containerView** with **tabBar** I want to add one more **tabBarItem** when Button Tapped on Any **viewController** Except **tabBarViewController** and **ContainerViewController**?

Comment: are you just looking to dynamically add view controllers to a tab bar?

Comment: i have a viewController which i want to show when the 4th tabBarItem Tapped.

Comment: i want to add more tabs from the view controller which is child view controller of container

Comment: Is your tabbarcontroller the rootViewcontroller? In the viewDidLoad method of the view controllers in the tab bar controller, you can trigger something to add another tab. viewDidLoad is not called on other tabs until they are requested.  So if you have 4 tabs.  The first one will call viewDidLoad right away, but 2,3, and 4 will only be loaded as requested.

Comment: Thank You @jacobbullock I done It

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After A While I Pass Notification When Button Tapped in Child View controller And Then I Catch That Notification in ContainerViewController And Then I Add The Tab Because It Cann't Give Me Access Of Tab Bar At any Of Child View Controller